# Lazy loading alternative to Model.all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Are there any alternative to `Model.all` which uses lazy loading? I noticed that returns `Array` instead of `ActiveRecord::Relation` like `where` or `order` methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `scoped` which will return a `ActiveRecord::Relation`

```
Model.scoped
```

Note: in Rails 4 the `scoped` method is deprecated, instead you can just use `all` which returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

Comment: Sounds nice, does it have any drawbacks? Like some issues together with scopes?

Comment: None that I can think of, this basically returns an anonymous scope. It will still use any default_scope and you can also chain any other scope you have defined for your model.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried it in console by chaining some scopes and it's perfect.